# What caching backends can be implemented in django

Tags: django, caching

Which of the caching strategies can be implemented in django?
What are the pros and cons of each cache backends (in terms of ease of use and ease of developing)?
Which backend should be preferred for production etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several backends that Django supports.
Listing a few here with comments around the positives and negatives of each.

- **Memcached**: The gold standard for caching. An in-memory service that can return keys at a very fast rate. Not a good choice if your keys are very large in size
- **Redis**: A good alternative to Memcached when you want to cache very large keys (for example, large chunks of rendered JSON for an API).
- **Dynamodb**: Another good alternative to Memcached when you want to cache very large keys. Also scales very well with little IT overhead.
- **Localmem**: Only use for local testing; don’t go into production with this cache type
- **Database**: It’s rare that you’ll find a use case where the database caching makes sense. It may be useful for local testing, but otherwise, avoid.
- **File system**: Can be a trap. Although reading and writing files can be faster than making sql queries, it has some pitfalls. Each cache is local to the application server (not shared), and if you have a lot of cache keys, you can theoretically hit the file system limit for number of files allowed.
- **Dummy**: A great backend to use for local testing when you want your data changes to be made immediately without caching. Be warned: permanently using dummy caching locally can hide bugs from you until they hit an environment where caching is enabled.

Comment: django doesn't support officially dynamodb as cache backend